# Problem about STM32 USB HOST CDC with CP20102

Tags: c, stm32, esp32, freertos, cdc

Before the main questions I Used STM32 and CubeIDE, FreeRTOS.

I want to communicate with arduino esp32 board and STM32 board.

STM32 will be use as host, and arduino will be use as device.

I am trying to implement communication between both boards using USART CDC.

However, when STM32 is connected to esp32 board, STM32's Applistate does not go from Application_START to Application_READY.

What is unknown is that if a USB memory other than esp32 is connected to STM32, Applistate is changed to Application_READY without any problem.

The tricky part is that USBH_OK cannot be returned when calling USBH_CDC_Transmit unless Applistate is changed to Application_READY.

How can I fix it so that USBH CDC can work normally?

TaskLocking is running always 1ms.

task.c

```
static void TaskLocking(void const *pvParameters){
    const char *pcTaskName = "TaskLocking";
    EventBits_t resultWaitBits;

    printf( "%s is running\r\n", pcTaskName );
    fflush(stdout);

    MX_FATFS_Init();
    MX_USB_HOST_Init();

    for(;;){
        resultWaitBits = xEventGroupWaitBits(event_locking, EVENT_LOCKING, pdFALSE, pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY);
        UNUSED(resultWaitBits);

        CDC_Process();
        //      cnt3++;

        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1));
    }

    printf( "%s is terminating\r\n", pcTaskName );
    fflush(stdout);

    vTaskDelete (NULL);
}
```

usb_cdc_util.c

```
#include "usb_cdc_util.h"
#include "usb_host.h"
#include "usbh_def.h"

extern USBH_HandleTypeDef hUsbHostFS;
extern ApplicationTypeDef Appli_state;
USBH_StatusTypeDef usbresult;

uint8_t CDC_RX_Buffer[RX_BUFF_SIZE];
uint8_t CDC_TX_Buffer[RX_BUFF_SIZE];

CDC_StateTypedef CDC_STATE = CDC_STATE_IDLE;

uint8_t tick_100ms_cnt;

uint8_t i=0;
void CDC_HANDLE (void)
{
//  switch (CDC_STATE)
//  {
//  case CDC_STATE_IDLE:
//  {
    if(++tick_100ms_cnt == 100){
        tick_100ms_cnt = CLEAR;
        USBH_CDC_Stop(&hUsbHostFS);
        int len = sprintf ((char *)CDC_TX_Buffer, "1");
        usbresult = USBH_CDC_Transmit (&hUsbHostFS, CDC_TX_Buffer, len);
        if (usbresult == USBH_OK)
        {
            CDC_STATE = CDC_RECEIVE;
        }
        i++;
    }
//      break;
//  }
//
//  case CDC_RECEIVE:
//  {
//      USBH_CDC_Stop(&hUsbHostFS);
//      usbresult = USBH_CDC_Receive(&hUsbHostFS, (uint8_t *) CDC_RX_Buffer, RX_BUFF_SIZE);
//      HAL_Delay (1000);
//      CDC_STATE = CDC_STATE_IDLE;
//  }
//
//  default:
//      break;
//  }
}

void CDC_Process(){
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    USBH_Process(&hUsbHostFS);

    if (Appli_state == APPLICATION_READY)
    {
        if(hUsbHostFS.device.DevDesc.idVendor == ESP32_HELTEC_VENDOR && hUsbHostFS.device.DevDesc.idProduct == ESP32_HELTEC_PRODUCT){
            CDC_HANDLE();
        }
    }

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
}
```

And..
.ioc setting

For reference, the esp32 connected to the USB port of the STM32 is receiving power without Vbus.

- 22.01.06

gState is USBH_ABORT_STATE

and Serial print out message was

[USB Device Connected
USB Device Reset Completed
PID: ea60h
VID: 10c4h
Address (#1) assigned.
Manufacturer : Silicon Labs
Product : CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
Serial Number : 0001
Enumeration done.
This device has only 1 configuration.
Default configuration set.
No registered class for this device.]

Comment: why do you use USB if you can simply wire the RX/TX pins together?

Comment: I want to use this USB for simple A/S for STM32 device. Just plug in Esp32 to STM32 device, they should communicate for share STM32 error logs and new firmware patch.

Comment: what is "A/S" and why is not doable over UART?

Comment: When I checked, the arduino board I connected to communicates through cp2102, so it was in the form of USB, but it was not.

Because of this, the CDC class was not supported, and this was the problem.

Thanks for your interest in the question.

Comment: you have two 3.3V MCU. connect their UART pins RX/TX directly without any converters